# Semi circle between 2 CGPoints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I want to draw a semi circle between 2 points on a circle. The main represents a clock and i want to draw another line to represent a progress from one hour to another so the points position may vary. First of all i know the X and Y of the 2 points i am interested in. This is how i try to add angles in UIBezierPath. My problem is that the new circle starts correctly but ends at a totally random location

````
let firstAngle = atan2(redPoint.y - circleCenter.y, redPoint.x - circleCenter.x)

let secondAngle = atan2(bluePoint.y - circleCenter.y, bluePoint.x - circleCenter.x) ```
````

````
    let circlePath1 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: circleCenter,
                                   radius: circleRadius,
                                   startAngle: firstAngle,
                                   endAngle: secondAngle,
                                   clockwise: true) ```
````

Wherever i set the redPoint, the circle starts at a correct location but the circle never ands at bluePoint.

[image: circle representation and points]

Comment: i changed the variable names while posing here to make question easier to follow. Changed it now to appear correct

Comment: I can't find an issue with your code. Make sure that you're using the same coordinate space for your points and your angles. I found this playground helpful to test bezier paths: https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/BezierPathPlaygrounds

Answer (score 2):

I have tried your code and it works for me if **points are** actually **on** that **circumference**

```
    let redPoint = CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 200.0)
    let bluePoint = CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 0.0)
    let circleCenter = CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0)

    let circleRadius = CGFloat(100.0)

    let firstAngle = atan2(redPoint.y - circleCenter.y, redPoint.x - circleCenter.x)

    let secondAngle = atan2(bluePoint.y - circleCenter.y, bluePoint.x - circleCenter.x)

    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: circleCenter,
                                radius: circleRadius,
                                startAngle: firstAngle,
                                endAngle: secondAngle,
                                clockwise: true)

    //Path in layer
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

[image]

or for example:

```
    let redPoint = CGPoint(x: 200.0, y: 100.0)
    let bluePoint = CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 0.0)
    let circleCenter = CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0)

    let circleRadius = CGFloat(100.0)
```

You get:

[image]

But if you use coordinates that are not actually on your circumference, you get wrong results. My suggestion is to check your inputs and eventually if points are belonging to your desired circumference or not.

Comment: thanks. I found my mistake. It was when converting current time to a point on the main circle. Instead of making the math from the circle origin i took the other point as reference so it messed up everything down. Bu thanks for the detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this backwards. Don't try to get the angle by starting with the location of the little red and blue filled circles. Use the angle to place the little red and blue filled circles.

[image]

In that example, my angles are -1 and 2.8 (radians). First I draw the arc (just as you did); then I superimpose the circles, which is trivial because I know where their centers are (the endpoints of the arc) by converting polar to cartesian coordinates.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit? The problem are not the color points, the problem is the arc. The points represent a specific hour on the clock so the arc must be between the 2 points. The input i get in code is for example point1=09h:40m point2=18h:25m

Comment: I do not know how to represent 09h:40m as a point on a circle. I don’t know what you want me to elaborate. I drew what you said you wanted to draw and I told you how I did it. If you give me any two angles the same sort of drawing will happen